# Print Checboxcolumn from Datagridview to Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I nee a help. I have a datagridview and have a checkboxcolumn in the last column. Which row is checked, it will be send to crystal report. In the crystal report, I only get the last checked even I check many records. Anyone can help me?
I use Vb.net

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count() - 1
        Dim cek As Boolean = CBool(row(i).Cells(5).Value)
        If cek = True Then
           count += 1
            Frm_HasilOrder.crv_hasilorder.SelectionFormula = "{tabelpasien.nama}='" + txt_namaOrder.Text + "' AND {all_kodeprmtr.kode} ='" + dgv1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value + "'" '.ToString()
        End If
    Next
    Frm_HasilOrder.crv_hasilorder.Refresh()
    Frm_HasilOrder.Show()
```

Comment: That's because you're looping and setting the selection formula for each checked row. In that case, all you will see when the code is done is the result of the last formula. What you have there is like painting a wall red, then painting it blue, then painting it green and expecting see all three colours. You need to get all IDs of the checked rows and then use an `IN` clause to get records with IDs in that list.

Comment: @jmcilhinney any suggestion? I've tried to get the checked row to dataset,, but always getting error in 'field name is not known"